# QCD in Coulomb Gauge Kernel Expansion

Tags: gauge-theory, hamiltonian, quantum-chromodynamics

I was re-reading the Hamiltonian QCD in Coulomb gauge section in Particle Physics and Introduction to Field Theory by T.D. Lee and I was trying to understand better the form of the Coulomb kernel that appears in the Coulomb term.

The expression for the Coulomb term in the Hamiltonian is

$$ K^{ab}(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}; \mathbf{A}) = <{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{A}^{a}|\frac{g}{\mathbf{\nabla}\cdot\mathbf{D}}(-\mathbf{\nabla}^2)\frac{g}{\mathbf{\nabla}\cdot\mathbf{D}}|\mathbf{y},\mathbf{A}^{b}}>,$$

with $\mathbf{D}^{ab}=\delta^{ab}\nabla+igf^{abc}\mathbf{A}^{c}.$ This kernel is proportional to the zero-th component of the gauge field,

$$A^{0,a}=<{r,a|\frac{1}{\mathbf{\nabla}\cdot\mathbf{D}}(-\mathbf{\nabla}^2)\frac{1}{\mathbf{\nabla}\cdot\mathbf{D}}|r',b}>g\rho^{a},$$

where $g$ is the coupling constant and $\rho^{a} = g\rho^{a}_{F}+gf^{abc}\mathbf{A}^{b}\cdot\mathbf{\Pi}^{c, tr}$.

Now, I understand that this kernel is formally a Coulomb interaction involving an infinite number of gluons that could be expanded in powers of $g$. However, in non-perturbative QCD, one generally models the Coulomb interaction as a Coulomb plus linear term of the from $\sim\frac{g^2}{r}+br$. If one takes the Abelian limit of the kernel above (That is, $\mathbf{D}\rightarrow\nabla$) one obtains the $\frac{1}{r}$ term, which one could think of as the zero-th term  in the expansion of $K^{ab}$, $K^{(0)}\sim\frac{1}{r}$. Hence, one could think of the Coulomb+linear model as the Abelian limit of the kernel with the addition of a linear term.

I have read in some papers that additional corrections to the Coulomb+linear term could be obtained by adding higher-order terms from the expansion of the kernel in powers of $g$. This is where I am having trouble. How does one expand the expression for $K^{ab}$ in powers of $g$? That is, how would one obtain, say, the first-order and second-order terms in the expansion?

I have a hard time understanding how to actually do this, given that the expression contains  covariant derivatives in the denominator and don't really know how to expand something that looks like

$$\frac{g}{\mathbf{\nabla}\cdot\mathbf{D}}(-\mathbf{\nabla}^2)\frac{g}{\mathbf{\nabla}\cdot\mathbf{D}}.
$$

Any expert input on this would be greatly appreciated.